# Qt 5.12 Mac OS X version number bug

Tags: c++, macos, qt, clang

When I attempt to `make` my C++ Qt project with I get the following error:

```
clang: error: invalid version number in '-mmacosx-version-min='
clang: error: invalid deployment target for -stdlib=libc++ (requires OS X 10.7 or later)
```

In fact, the console writes:

`-mmacosx-version-min= -Wl`

so it appears that this target OS X version is not specified (or specified incorrectly) to clang even though I passed

`QMAKE_MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET = 10.7`

in `.qmake.conf`.

Is there a way get around this bug?

> **Note:** This first happened when I tried to link a library using statlib c++11. When I run `make` without the library it builds without a hitch.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same problem.

`-mmacosx-version-min=` was set in `mkspecs/features/mac/default_post.prf` where the `deployment_target` variable was incorrectly initialized due to CONFIG `macos` token check. In my case it should be `macx`.

So there was a choice either to add `macos` token to the `CONFIG` variable or patch default_post.prf.